# How do I prevent the GUI overlay from disappearing when I play videos in fullscreen?

Tags: autohotkey

I made a screen dimmer in AHK. The code below is a stripped-down version:

```
opacity := 100
Gui 1:New,+AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow +E0x20, GuiName
Gui 1:Color,Black
Gui 1:Show, x800 y300 h300 w300
WinSet Transparent, %opacity%, A
Return
```

The GUI overlay disappears whenever I play video in fullscreen. It happens in Native Media Player, PotPlayer, and KMPlayer.

It works fine in VLC, but I don't use it because it lacks the ability to "play next video" when I click "next" unless I add all the videos in a playlist.

Comment: Crosspost with potential answer/workaround: https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/1av8jtz/how_do_i_prevent_the_gui_overlay_from/